# Why can't boolean expressions be supported by default when performing pattern matching on a value?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

For example:

```
match (x) {
    x > 0 => // expression, notice this `x > 0` is a bool expr while x itself is a int
    _     => // ... 
}
```

instead of having to use syntax like `x when x > 0`? Is it a bit verbose? Why can't it be simplified?

Comment: Because match arms are patterns, not expressions. `x > 0` isn't a pattern. However, I would think that `0..` should work.

Comment: `x @ 1..` is the pattern that corresponds to `x if x > 0`, at least for Rust

Comment: Oops, right, I meant `1..`.

Comment: if only we could do `match x > 0 { true =>`... but shorter like `if x > 0`... if only

Comment: I don't see any [tag:functional-programming] here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to test whether `x > 0` the thing to use is an `if`. `match` is for matching against patterns, not testing Boolean expressions.

Comment: "The right tool for the job" is as common an expression as it is for a reason.